# How to install WINE to support multiple users

Tags: macos, wine

I have installed WINE using the instructions at the [WineHQ Wiki](http://wiki.winehq.org/MacOSX) and was able to successfully run an install of a Windows application for my admin user.  Buoyed by my success I thought I would try to get it working for the multiple users I have on my machine (read: family).  I found the [multiple users](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-f54d469b937b82e6d757a851dfcece0167919859) stub in the [FAQ](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ) and have made a number of modifications by following the instructions in the [ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=917422).  I believe I followed them properly.  It essentially has you set up the sudoers file to support other users having the ability to operate as another user without a password.  In this case I've created a 'windows' user that executes WINE.
The issue I'm having is that I'm receiving the following error when attempting to execute an application that previously worked under the admin account.

```
$ sudo -u windows -H wine application.exe
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied
Dynamic session lookup supported but failed: launchd did not provide a socket path, verify that org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist is loaded!
err:menubuilder:init_xdg error looking up the desktop directory
wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\application.exe"
```

I'm not new to Linux but am new to Mac and to WINE, so thank you for any direction you can provide.

Comment: Have all files got permissions to read as the windows user (and the current directory) and the directors between them an /

Comment: @McArthey have you tried (Wineskin)[http://wineskin.urgesoftware.com/tiki-index.php]. It gives simpler interface to run your applications using wine

Comment: I haven't seen wineskin but I will look into it.  Thanks for the tip.